# Material Shader not showing Materials

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

I was working on a project in blender 2.92, I have put many hours into this and really hope there is a solution.

After working I saved file. When I returned to file I found that when in solid view all was good but when I wanted to check in the Material Shader view (LookDev) is shows just a dark model. This also happens in Renders mode.

I get this issue with a new blend file too.

All setting seem ok. As far as I am aware I didn't change anything.

[image: This is in LookDev and also Rendered View]
[image: This is in LookDev and also Rendered View]

Comment: unfortunately, that screen shot doesn't really show us anything about your materials.  Please add your blend file to your question (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Possibly a fog/mist issue if you have any of them turned on.